# Is there an easy way to transfer files between PCs and a phone via WiFi?

Tags: wi-fi, file-transfer

I'm currently using SFTP to send files between my phone and my Linux PCs, with OpenSSH server on the PCs and Ghost Commander on the phone. What is inconvenient is that I have to either type the password each time (on screen keyboard!), store it on the phone, or try to setup `authorized_keys` (which I'm hesitant to do for a mobile device, since it lets it do anything, not only send files). Using something like an FTP server without authorization is not an option: I don't want to get files from everyone around without a means to reject a transfer.

I'd like to be able to simply "offer" to send a file to the PC and, when the PC accepts this offer (the user clicks "Yes"), do the transfer; similarly in backwards direction — much like Bluetooth file transfers work.

Is there any software (zero-cost and ad-free) offering such functionality?

Comment: KDEConnect app allows sending files to paired devices. But its Linux variant  does not have a feature to approve receiving. It just sends them. Have you tried that app?

Comment: @Firelord haven't tried it yet, but that "Linux variant" doesn't have a feature that presumably some other variant (Windows?) does have seems strange for a KDE project.

Comment: I don't know about Windows variant or even the most recent Linux variant (I use an older version on an older KDE (4.x release)). You can try it and see for yourself.

Comment: Instead of using third party closed source solutions, SFTP is best, if speed is not a concern. Setup an SFTP chroot if you don't want to *let it do anything*. I run an SSHD server on my phone (as unprivileged UID and with dropped capabilities) which I can access from PC (Linux + Windows), mostly through SSHFS for easy access in file explorers.

Comment: @Firelord OK, tried it. Although it's a nice piece of software in general, silent acceptance of files is not good. And I failed to make the version in Ubuntu 14.04 work with current version for Android, although the one in 18.04 does work. Apparently, their protocol is not stable enough, changing between versions.